# MultiBinding in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

How to implement MultiBinding in Silverlight 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an implementation that works slightly differently: http://www.olsonsoft.com/blogs/stefanolson/post/Improvements-to-Silverlight-Multi-binding-support.aspx
It lets you write code like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Block" Foreground="White" FontSize="13"
           Margin="5,0,0,0">
    <local:BindingUtil.MultiBindings>
        <local:MultiBindings>
            <local:MultiBinding TargetProperty="Text" Converter="{StaticResource TitleConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Surname"/>                            
                <Binding Path="Forename"/>
            </local:MultiBinding>
            <local:MultiBinding TargetProperty="Visibility" Converter="{StaticResource TitleToVisibiltyConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Surname"/>                            
                <Binding Path="Forename"/>
            </local:MultiBinding>
        </local:MultiBindings>
    </local:BindingUtil.MultiBindings>
</TextBlock>
```

Ordinarily I don't like linking to people's blogs, but the code is just way too big to post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one implementation that allows up to 5 bindings: http://www.thejoyofcode.com/MultiBinding_for_Silverlight_3.aspx
It lets you write code like this:

```
<binding:MultiBinding x:Name="mb" Converter="{StaticResource intsToBrushConverter}"
    NumberOfInputs="3"
    Input1="{Binding ElementName=red, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Input2="{Binding ElementName=green, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Input3="{Binding ElementName=blue, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<Border Background="{Binding ElementName=mb, Path=Output}" Margin="5"/>
```